# How should I properly implement the core Clojure interfaces?

Tags: data-structures, interface, clojure, abstraction

If I'm implementing some data structure in Clojure using `deftype`, how should I decide which of the [core Clojure interfaces](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang) to implement?

I was unable to find a comprehensive guide to the various Clojure interfaces; in fact, the only relevant piece of information I *was* able to find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313824/should-i-implement-the-seq-interface-in-clojure), which is very limited in scope.

What I'm looking for is a list of each of the core Clojure interfaces, with a brief description of what it is and when you should implement it (or if you should even implement it at all!), as well as a list of all the common functions in `clojure.core` that use it. A description or diagram of the inheritance tree of all these interfaces would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excellent book [*Clojure Applied*](https://pragprog.com/book/vmclojeco/clojure-applied) by Ben Vandgrift and Alex Miller provides detailed information on this exact topic in "Chapter 2. Collect and Organize Your Data", under "Building Custom Collections". A visual diagram of interfaces in `clojure.lang` is provided on page 39.

Answer (score 3):

i can not answer all your questions but I usually start from clojure atlas http://www.clojureatlas.com/ to find which interfaces to implement.

Comment: That looks awesome! I had no idea that existed. Unfortunately, I can't accept your answer for the reason you stated.